# React Native - Clear Async Storage Script

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, asyncstorage

I'm currently building a react native app which uses async storage. I've got conditionals within the components to decide whether to make requests to the API or use the data stored in memory. So to test out these conditionals I regularly have to clear the AsyncStorage using `AsyncStorage.clear()`.

This works if I have it in one of the components, however it would be more practical to have it in a seperate script - which brings me to my question:

I want to have a script as below:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
AsyncStorage.clear();
console.log('STORAGE CLEARED');
```

and then run it using a command like `node clearStorage.js` (and later an npm script).

However I'm getting an error saying  'Cannot use import statement outside a module'.

Am I missing anything glaringly obvious/trying to do something I shouldn't? I've tried changing the file type to `.mjs` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this, you can't use a nodejs script because the node script will never get to the native side, because async-storage is a native library and it connects directly to Android or IOS.

Another solution may be at the start of the application, you can run that code, or create a Button just for dev mode and when click clean the data.

and the error 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'. it's because nodeJs don't understand the syntax `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';` they need a transpiler like babel.

Comment: ok thanks, that's the answer I was looking for, at the moment I have a conditional
which does the job. Looks like I'll keep it in for dev purposes. Thanks!